.Htaccess Customize Query String
I am using the code below.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brands=(.*)&features=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^products/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?brands=%1&features=%2

However, this requires both values. For example, it does not work when only the brand value is given.
Example: x.com/?products?brands=2,4,5 Does not work
Example: x.com/?products?brands=2,4,5&features=3,6,8 Works
What causes this and what is the solution? Also, how can I fully customize the parameters.
So how can I make the key and value unique?
Example: x.com/products?any=any&any=any.....

If you want to forward query string as is to index.php then simply use: RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php [L,NC] and query string will be available inside index.php as well.

The issue is that your RewriteCond expects both brands and features to be present. To make them optional, update your rules like this:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)brands=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)features=([^&]*)|brands= [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?brands=%2&features=%3 [L,QSA]


The first condition checks for brands (optional).
The second condition checks for features or ensures brands exists.
The RewriteRule passes the values to index.php.

If you want to pass all query parameters dynamically, you would have :
RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

This simply passes the query string (QUERY_STRING) to your script

The issue with your existing code is that it's written to specifically match both brands and features query parameters in the QUERY_STRING. When only one of the parameters (brands) is passed, the regular expression in the RewriteCond (^brands=(.)&features=(.)$) does not match, and thus the rule doesn't fire. This is why x.com/?products?brands=2,4,5 does not work.
The current condition (RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brands=(.)&features=(.)$) expects both brands and features to be present in the query string, so if features is missing, the regular expression fails.
Solution:
To fix this, we need to modify the condition to handle cases where either brands or features is present. Additionally, to support flexible custom parameters with dynamic keys, we should allow the possibility of matching optional parameters in the query string.
Step 1: Modify the RewriteCond to handle optional parameters
We will update the regular expression to match the brands and features parameters if they are present, but also allow for missing parameters.
If you want to fully customize the parameters and make the key-value pairs flexible (e.g., x.com?any=any&another=another), you can modify your RewriteCond to match any key-value pair in the query string.
Here's an example of how to make the parameters dynamic:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)([^=]+)=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^products/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?%2=%3 [L]

Notes:
The new code will allow flexible key-value pairs in the query string, where the keys and values are dynamic, such as any=any or brands=2,4,5&features=3,6,8.
This method will rewrite all parameters dynamically based on the query string content.

The example you gave only gives the first parameter. It does not appear when there is a second parameter.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)([^=]+)=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^products/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?
page=category&sef=$1&%2=%3&%4=%5
?brands=1,2,5&features=3,6,8
Only brands work.
